# Proof that the following linear operator is surjective with bounded inverse.

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider a linear operator $S\in L(H)$ (meaning $S$ is linear and continuous/bounded), where $H$ is a Hilbert space such that there is $M$:

$$|(Sx,x)|\geq M\|x\|^2$$

Where $(Sx,x)$ is the inner product. I want to show that $S$ is surjective and the inverse is bounded by:

$$\|S^{-1}\|\leq 1/M$$

I have tried to show that $S$ is bounded, and then from that the first result follows, not quite sure how to solve the second identity. Tips on the problem are very welcome.

Comment: Okay, I have found out an answer from somewhere else, it is super long, if you are able to look for the book, Alberto Torchinsky, *Problems in Real and Functional Analysis*, page 164, 460, the solution is there, good luck.

Comment: You may look at the edited answer, see if it is correct.

Comment: @user284331 Yes! This is the correct proof, better than the book ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, $Sx=0$ implies that $\|x\|\leq 0$ and hence $x=0$, so $S$ is injective.

Now we have $M\|S^{-1}x\|^{2}\leq|(SS^{-1}x,S^{-1}x)|=|(x,S^{-1}x)|\leq\|x\|\|S^{-1}x\|$ and hence $M\|S^{-1}x\|\leq\|x\|$, so $\|S^{-1}x\|\leq M^{-1}\|x\|$, this means that $\|S^{-1}\|\leq M^{-1}$.

Assume that the range $R(S)$ of $S$ is not $H$, then $R(S)^{\perp}\ne\{0\}$, say, $0\ne y\in R(S)^{\perp}$, then $(Sy,y)=0$ because of $Sy\in R(S)$. But then $M\|y\|^{2}=0$, it follows that $y=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, the equality in the question was wrong way ;).

Comment: Great answer. Do you mean that injective implies surjective, by which theorem is this?

Comment: No, it doesn't imply surjectivity. But are you sure that the problem asks also for surjectivity?

Comment: Yes :-), so that the inverse is proper.

Comment: Is it given that $M>1$?

Comment: Only that $M>0$.

Comment: Just came to mind, it is enough to show that $S$ is open, perhaps easier...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The mistake is corrected, the statement is now correct. If you have ideas on the surjectivity, it seems difficult to prove.

Comment: To get from $R(Sne H$ to $R(S)\perp\ne\{0\}$ you need that $R(S)$ is _closed_. Which of course is very simple,  but it needs to be done.

Comment: @Tony " If you have ideas on the surjectivity, it seems difficult to prove." ??? The fact that $||S||\ge c||$|| shows that $R(S)$ is closed. Given that, the last paragraph of the accepted answer gives a very simple  proof that $R(S)=H$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, it is clear now...