# if bounded linear operator $T$ is positive definite,then $T$ has a bounded inverse $T^{-1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let X be a complex Hilbert space with the inner product $\langle⋅,⋅\rangle$ and norm $||⋅||$. Suppose T is a bounded linear operator on $X$ and $T$ is positive definite, means there is a constant $K>0$, such that $K\langle x,x\rangle \leq \langle T(x),x\rangle$, prove $T$ has a bounded inverse $T^{-1}$ and the norm of $T^{-1}$ is less than or equal to $K$.

I simply put $K$ into the inner product, then $K\langle x,x\rangle \leq \langle T(x),x\rangle$, is that means  $Kx \leq T(x)$? hope get prove of this question

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447032/proof-that-the-following-linear-operator-is-surjective-with-bounded-inverse

Comment: @user284331 thanks you so much!

Comment: @conditionalMethod thank you so much!

Comment: Pay special attention to whether you know $(Tx,x)\geq K(x,x)$ or you are trying to deduce it.